# Random Number Generation: Are these probabilities the same?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I want to generate a random number - which I can do two ways.

1. I can write a function `F(start, end)` that generates a random number between start and end (inclusive)
2. I can write another function `G(length)` that generates a random number of specified length by choosing each unit, tens, ... place randomly from `[0, 1, 2, ... 9]`

Are these functions equivalent?
`F(0, 100)` == `G(2)`

Also, in general are these two approaches equivalent - assuming that the `F` is not implemented in terms of `G`

Comment: You cannot get $100$ from $G(2)$ but you can from $F(0,100)$

Comment: Assuming the actual end points match up, yes, they should be equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G(2)$ is equivalent to $F(0,99)$.